# conditional permutation of strings

Tags: python-3.x, permutation

I am trying to print arrangement of numbers with following conditions

> The number at the ith position is divisible by i.
>
> i is divisible by the number at the ith position.

```
def permutation(lst):
  if len(lst) == 0:
     return []

  if len(lst) == 1:
    return [lst]

  l = []

  for i in range(len(lst)):
    m = lst[i]
    if m % (i + 1) == 0 or (i + 1) % m == 0:
      remLst = lst[i + 1:] + lst[:i]
      for p in permutation(remLst):
        l.append([m] + p)

  return l
```

When I run the output for `permutation([1,2,3))` I am getting
`[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]`

here output `[2,3,1]` is wrong . I have added the condition but I can't filter out these arrangements

Comment: So `[3, 1, 2]`, `[3, 2, 1]` are wrong too right?

Comment: @blhsing yes they are wrong too

Comment: 1) Your recursive call doesn't seem to maintain the indices from the original input array. 2) You will get an element in the result as long as the first element satisfies the condition of divisibility and there are results from permutation of the remainder (with shifted indices) -- which is always. What is your condition -- is it either a) At least one element should satisfy the divisibility or, b) All the elements should satisfy the divisibility ?

Comment: @UltraInstinct all the elements should satisfy divisibility. so if any one breaks the rule I discard the whole arrangement

Comment: You might need to fix #1 in my comment above -- you'll need to pass something like `start_index` to `permutation(..)` and condition evaluation should use `1 + start_index` instead of `i + 1`. IMO, that should fix it. :)